# Prove a distribution is continuous from right

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose we have $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$,  define $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$ for $-\infty<x<\infty$. Hence the defined distribution function should have property $F(x)=F(x+)$, i.e.  the function is continuous from right.

By definition of $F(x)$, we know it is a $P(X\leq x)$, hence we just need to let $P(X\leq x+1/n)$ and by continuity of $P$, we know $P(\bigcap^\infty_{n=1}(-\infty,x+a_n])=P(-\infty,x]$ provided that $a_n$ is a decreasing sequence with $n$, hence we have shown $F(x+)=F(x)$. However, I am puzzled by the proof I have just shown because we also know a measure is continuous from below too. Won't that suggest $P(\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}(-\infty,x_n-a_n])=P((-\infty,x_n])$, and result in
concluding $F(x-)=F(x)$?

However, this is clearly not the case for any discrete random variable. I suspect it has something to do with $F(x)$ being defined as $P(X\leq x)$, if $F(x)$ is instead defined as $F(x)=P(X<x)$, the conclusion could be other way around. It continuity of $F$ is very easy to think about when drawing the graph; however, when it comes to proof I find myself unable to identify the problem.

Could someone please explain to me where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You just have in general $$P(\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}(-\infty,x_n-1/n])=P((-\infty,x_n)) \not= P((-\infty,x_n]) = F(x)$$

Comment: Just as a remark: @Gono is correct about the reasoning. However, OP, in your proof, you technically haven't proved continuity. It seems like you are using the theorem that  $F$ is continuous from the right at $x$ iff for every sequence $\{x_n\}$, $x_n>x$ for all $n$, with $x_n \to x$, we have $F(x_n) \to F(x)$. 

In your proof, you technically only did the special case $x_n=x+\frac{1}{n}$. Try generalizing it with the same approach. Using the continuity of measure over decreasing sets, but use unions of events to construct such a sequence of decreasing sets.

Comment: @Gono oh yea, thanks for reminding me this

Comment: @zugzug thank you ! I have changed 1/n to $a_n$, and make it a decreasing sequence. And yes, I did use that theorem! I tried to use the $\epsilon - \delta$ method to prove the results but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: That's the idea. By the way, personally, I think the notation is better to write $x+a_n$ as just $x_n$ with $x_n>x$ for all $n$, rather than $a_n>0$ for all $n$. Also, I would clean up your sets better and be more precise. You aren't measuring the probability $P((-\infty,x])$, for example, but rather $P(\{\omega: X(\omega)\leq x\})$. This is different, as it actually makes use of the random variable.

Basically, what's happening is the events $A_n=\cap_{k=1}^n \{\omega: X(\omega)\leq x_k\}$ form a decreasing sequence of events. Then you use continuity of measure from above.

Comment: @zugzug Thank you! I have also thought that the proof is not rigorous enough! But yes! it seems let $A_{n}=\cap_{k-1}^{n}\left\{\omega: X(\omega) \leq x_{k}\right\}$ would make the $F(x_n)\rightarrow F(x)$ makes more sense!